# auto caption for images doesn't work: img[title]:after{content:attr(title);}

Tags: css

i want to using the TITLE attribute of the IMG tag, create captions for images:

HTML

```
<img src="some.jpg" title="imgtitle" />
```

CSS

```
img[title]:after{content:attr(title);}
```

But both in IE, Firefox or Google Chrome, it does not work, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't use pseudo elements with images. Just one of those limitations. I can't find a reference right now though...

**EDIT:** http://css-tricks.com/vignetting-woes/ there is a mention in there

> No elements with an 'empty' Content Model support generated-content via pseudo-elements